# HTML Outlook Signature issues

Tags: html, email, outlook

I am having a hard time with this email signature.  It looks fine in the browser, the issue is when I copy and paste into the signature box in outlook.  I know CSS doesn't apply with outlook signatures.

The logo is on the right.  Aligned to the top are the person and job title, aligned to the bottom is the phone number and email.  The issue is that when I replace the picture files with text (which looks better), the cells change size somewhat and affect the size of the logo.

Is there a way to code this better?  Is there a way to force the rows to be a particular size, thus not skewing the adjoining cells?  In the end, I want the top rows aligned to the top of the logo, and the bottom rows aligned to the bottom.

Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
<title>Grapa VFD V4</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (Signature Template1 (1).psdc) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="368" height="178" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <img src="https://grapaes.com/signatures/Virtual%20AFD/Code3/1_01.png?_t=1592826006" width="368" height="9" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="https://grapaes.com/signatures/Virtual%20AFD/Code3/1_02.png?_t=1592826006" width="12" height="91" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="https://grapaes.com/signatures/Virtual%20AFD/Code3/1_03.png?_t=1592826006" width="89" height="91" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="https://grapaes.com/signatures/Virtual%20AFD/Code3/1_04.png?_t=1592826006" width="22" height="91" alt=""></td>
        <td width="245" height="36" valign="top"><span style="font-size: 10.5pt; font-family:'malgun gothic', sans-serif, Arial; color: #646568; font-weight: 700; letter-spacing: .28px;">Person</span><br>
            <span style="font-size: 10.5pt; font-family:'malgun gothic', sans-serif, Arial; color: #749b53; font-weight: 700; letter-spacing: .28px;">Job Title</span>
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="https://grapaes.com/signatures/Virtual%20AFD/Code3/1_06.png?_t=1592826006" width="245" height="27" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="245" height="28" valign="top">
            <img src="https://grapaes.com/signatures/Virtual%20AFD/Code3/1_07.png?_t=1592826006" width="245" height="28" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <img src="https://grapaes.com/signatures/Virtual%20AFD/Code3/1_08.png?_t=1592826006" width="368" height="78" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check all your `colspan`, make sure they add up

Comment: Thanks.  They do add up I believe.